# get comments by current user inside page template

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, users, page-template

I want to add a page template inside my custom post type and retrieve inside that page the comments posted by current user.

I have this code for getting the current user:

```
<!-- GET CURRENT USER -->

<?php

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
?>
```

The code for getting the comments of the current user:

```
<!-- GET COMMENTS OF USER -->
<?php 
$args = array(
'user_id' => 1, // use user_id
    'post_type' => 'my-CPT',
 );
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;

?>
```

And the code for listing the comments:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'outbox_comment' ) );
            ?>
</ol><!-- .commentlist -->
```

And this is how my **page-commentsbyuser.php** is looking:

```
<?php

/**
 * The template for displaying a list of comment from the current user
 *
 */

get_header();

    ?>
<div id="primary" class="row">

    <div id="content" class="span9" role="main">

<!-- GET CURRENT USER -->   
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
?>
    <!-- GET COMMENTS OF USER -->

<?php 
$args = array(
'user_id' => 1, // use user_id
    'post_type' => 'my-CPT',
 );
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;

?>
    <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'outbox_comment' ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->
    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->

</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

This is not working and also I don't know how can I get the comments of the current user.

Any suggestions on how I can retrieve the comments from the  CPT  of the current user inside this page template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not working and also I don't know how can I get the comments
>   of the current user.

You have already used the current user's ID in your code...

```
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
```

... but you hard-code a single ID in the `get_comments` argument array. Don't do that. Use the current user ID.

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $current_user->ID, // use user_id
    'post_type' => 'my-CPT',
);
```

I am uncertain of the relationship between your user comments and `wp_list_comments`. You have already output the user comments so I don't why you are running `wp_list_comments` unless you are trying to output a different set of comment or you are trying to output the same comments again (which is weird). Either way, you need to pass `wp_list_comments` a set of comments as in [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) (re-formatted to be less confusing):

```
//Gather comments for a specific page/post 
$comments = get_comments(
  array(
    'post_id' => XXX,
    'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
  )
);

//Display the list of comments
wp_list_comments(
  array(
    'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
    'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
  ), 
  $comments
);
```

Note the second argument `$comments`, which is the output of a call to `get_comments`. The context you seem to be using this in makes me think that that is going to be required.

Comment: Now is working !  I've noticed that ` <ol class="commentlist">` is empty also, is this supposed to be empty or is something wrong?

Comment: @Alecs : see the edit